Getting Remote side sent SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO after USERAUTH_SUCCESS on mobaxterm
I am getting Remote side sent SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO after USERAUTH_SUCCESS on mobaxterm after some times,
I tried to google up but couldn't find solution.
This one say to adjust the PuTTY's Connection/SSH/Kex/Max minutes, but I can't find the putty settings in mobaxterm PuTTY Fatal Error: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
ANother URL say to make changes in the server end(Which i dont agree because if i am using putty alone), I do not face such error , it just happen when i am using mobaxterm.
https://blog.csdn.net/wnw_jackie/article/details/127727517
I am hoping if anyone face similar issue and if you have any solution to fix this from client end, please let me know, much appreciate :)
